# Reason for opening multiple terminals for processs?

Tags: linux, unix, terminal

I've often seen tech tutorials in which I'm supposed to open a terminal per program/process where actually I feel no need for doing so (no output on terminals, no termination via terminal etc.), and instead I can run all programs background with `&` at the end. Is there still advantages / technical reasons for using multiple terminals?

(not versatile at all but an example is [this tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/UsingRqtconsoleRoslaunch))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is probably largely because it's easier to explain that than it is to explain how to start a program in the background. A part may also be that instructions use something like "export X=something" and they don't want to cause problems for another process later on, that may not behave as expected from this.

But generally, you can just use one terminal window, or one terminal with several tabs, if you prefer that solution. Different people have different ideas of "the right way to do things" - as long as it works as expected and every time, it's not a huge issue which way you do it.

Aside from envirnonment variables, I don't see any technical reason to have multiple terminals.

Answer (score 0):

commands that you run on the terminal will use the same terminal (stdout) to flush info/warning or error messages. You can run all those commands in background if you want, like you said using & but then it gets difficult to keep track of any messages that those programs may produce. everything will be displayed on same console.

Comment: Good point. If there is OUTPUT from the application to stdout/stderr, then it can get messy.

Comment: Yeah I've realized that the output gets messy as I implied in my original Q. I'm curious if there are technical reasons.